# Aiming to discern verbs and what may get requested to go after them or not

Tags: verbs

I think I may get transitive verbs, (request an argument after them) and intransitive verbs, (may not request an argument after them).

> "Being chosen is".

I think this got discerned a complete sentence. So a copulative verb *is* may not request an argument. So it may seem intransitive?

May this seem a complete sentence?

> I won't.

I, subject, will, modal verb(?), not, adverb.

There seems no noun here, no object.
I think I may get transitive and intransitive verbs. May copulative (copular[?]) verbs and modal verbs request an argument, object, noun after them?

Answer (score 4):

To be a complete sentence the copula *is*, which is the verb heading the clause, requires a complement; for instance:

> Being chosen is a great honor.

The construction *BE* + the past participle of a verb is the [*passive voice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice). In this construction, the object of the active verb (the 'Patient' which is acted on) becomes the subject of the passive construction, with the active-voice subject (the 'Agent', the person performing the action) left unexpressed, or expressed with a *by* phrase. But this is only a syntactical change; the semantic relationships are unchanged. The construction is employed to move the 'focus' of the sentence, or to avoid expressing the Agent

> <sub>subject</sub>The voters<sup>agent</sup>     **chose**         <sub>object</sub>John<sup>patient</sup>.  =
>         <sub>subject</sub>John<sup>patient</sup>   **was chosen**   by the voters<sup>agent</sup>.

- Note that (aside from a category of exceptions which I won't go into here), **only** transitive verbs can be cast in the passive voice, because only transitive verbs have objects which can be cast as the subject of a passive construction.

In your example, the verb *BE* is cast in the *-ing* form and acts as a gerund. In this particular case the subject of *being chosen* (the Patient of *choose*) is also omitted; presumably it can be inferred from the context.

Comment: I think I got *Being chosen is* from *Being chosen, however, is probably not enough.* I think someone did text that *is* seemed that verb there.

Comment: In *Being chosen is*, *Being* a participle verb that gets into a gerund noun phrase *Being chosen*, *is* seems a copulative (copular[?]) verb? In passive voice, it seems a thing done gets placed like a do-er? So, *Being chosen* seems an argument of a copular verb *is*? And I guess that may signify a copular verb, *is*, seems transitive. It may request an argument, a subject, and what may customarily seem a thing done, object, (patient[?]), in this, passive voice, gets placed as a do-er, noun phrase, subject (agent[?]).

Comment: I thank you StoneyB, I think I got some information formerly upon maybe *Being chosen is* that seemed to get me to maybe think that. I think I may mostly get what you did text upon.